# Multi-dimensional array comprehension in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia, list-comprehension

I can create the following (length(X),) array:

```
[F(x) for x in X]
```

However, if F(x) returns an array, is there anyway way to create a multidimensional array using comprehension where each row is F(x), and the dimensions of the array are `(length(X),length(F(x))`?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to directly do that with an array comprehension, but there are various ways to turn a vector of vectors into a matrix (some of which are described here on Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to do this in Julia! Following your use of comprehensions, a simple way to turn the array output of `F(x)` into a 2-dimensional array would be to concatenate the results, either with [`vcat`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.vcat), [`hcat`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.hcat), or the more generic [`cat`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.cat), and using a [`reduce`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.reduce-Tuple%7BAny,Any%7D) operation over the arguments:

```
F(x) = [x, x*2, x*3]
X = collect(1:5)
reduce(vcat, [F(x)' for x in X])
# 5×3 Array{Int64,2}:
#  1   2   3
#  2   4   6
#  3   6   9
#  4   8  12
#  5  10  15
```

Because you specifically requested a `length(X)` by `length(F(x))` array, the adjoint operator [`'`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#Base.adjoint) has to be used on the output of `F(x)` to orient it properly for `vcat`. You can also do the same with `hcat` and transpose the result:

```
reduce(hcat, [F(x) for x in X])'
# 5×3 LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Int64,Array{Int64,2}}:
#  1   2   3
#  2   4   6
#  3   6   9
#  4   8  12
#  5  10  15
```

The `reduce` call is required because `vcat` and `hcat` concatenate together all of their arguments--if you just give them `[F(x) for x in X]`, they will assume you are passing one single array of arrays and simply return that because there is nothing to concatenate.

You should also take a look at [function broadcasting](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.Broadcast.broadcast), a feature that sets Julia apart from many other languages. It can help reduce the verbosity of code that in other languages relies on list comprehensions. Just add a period after your function name and before the arguments to automatically broadcast the function over all of the elements of the argument!

```
Y = collect(2:2:10)
reduce(hcat, F.(Y))'
# 5×3 LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Int64,Array{Int64,2}}:
#   2   4   6
#   4   8  12
#   6  12  18
#   8  16  24
#  10  20  30
```

### Advanced: Function Composition

As @CameronBiegnanek points out, Julia supports [function composition](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Function-composition-and-piping) using the `∘` operator. Composing two functions together like `(G ∘ F)(x)` translates to `G(F(x))`, so you can compose the `adjoint` operation with your function `F` like this:

```
reduce(vcat, (adjoint ∘ F).(X))
```

But this kind of operation (*mapping* a function over all elements of an array, then *reducing* all of those outputs using another function) is a common way of processing data known as a "map-reduce" operation. Julia has a built-in [`mapreduce`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.mapreduce-Tuple%7BAny,Any,Any%7D) function to do just that!

```
mapreduce(adjoint ∘ F, vcat, X)
```

Comment: Generally `reduce(vcat, A)` is recommended over splatting like `vcat(A...)`, because splatting a large number of arguments is not very efficient. Base Julia has optimized methods for `reduce(vcat, A)` and `reduce(hcat, A)`.

Comment: And the reducing and the mapping can be combined into one call: `mapreduce(adjoint ∘ F, vcat, X)`.

Comment: Great points, @CameronBieganek! I updated the answer with `reduce` and will add the fancy function composition.

Comment: Instead of using an array comprehension, you can use a generator. The comprehension will allocate a temporary array before concatenating, but the generator won't. Try for example `reduce(hcat, F(x) for x in X)'` without square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

If `F(x)` returns a tuple or a [StaticArray](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl), the upcoming Julia 1.6 will allow you to do what you're asking like this:

```
reinterpret(reshape, T, [F(x) for x in X])
```

Demo:

```
julia> reinterpret(reshape, Int, [(i, i+1) for i=1:4])
2×4 reinterpret(reshape, Int64, ::Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}) with eltype Int64:
 1  2  3  4
 2  3  4  5
```